# How come Revtex says acknowledgements are obsolete?

Tags: warnings, revtex, obsolete

Running revtex4-1 with the preamble:

```
\documentclass[aps, pre, floatfix, reprint]{revtex4-1}
```

and the section later:

```
\begin{acknowledgements}
The authors would like to thank Tex, LaTeX and Friends 
for the answer to this question.
\end{acknowledgements}
```

Gives the warning:

```
 Class revtex4-1 Warning: Environment acknowledgements is obsolete;
```

Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: If I could (rep. deficient) I would tag this as 'revtex' but no tags exists at the moment.

Comment: Tagged it for you.

Comment: Very nice example! Since it's not an error, I changed that tag to [warning].

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have never used `revtex` but the [author's guide](https://authors.aps.org/revtex4/auguide4-1.pdf) explicitly states:

> Please note the spelling of “acknowledgments.”

This is also the full error message LaTeX produces:

> Class revtex4-1 Warning: Environment acknowledgements is obsolete;
>   Use acknowledgments instead.

So replacing `acknowledgements` by `acknowledgments` removes the message.

Comment: This is what I get for compiling in a GUI instead of the command-line. Winefish cuts off the warning, so I never got to see the last part (though grammar hints that the semicolon should give more information). Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: For other readers, which might be thick like me and have difficulties to see the difference: no 'e' between 'acknowledg' and 'ment'